# What is RecyclerView.Adapter's counterpart of ListView.Adpater.isEnabled()

Tags: android, api, listview, android-recyclerview

I am trying to convert [library](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) from listview to recyclerview.

I am not able to change this following line of code:

```
swipeListView.getAdapter().isEnabled(childPosition)
```

because when I try following:

```
recyclerView.getAdapter().isEnabled(childPosition)
```

it says isEnabled can not be resolved